# Mootools: Fading between divs in menu

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools

I have a menu with at the left 4 <li> items, and at the right there are 4 divs, one per item, and entering an item with the mouse should display one of the divs.
something like

```
<ul><li onmouseover="javascript:showDiv("div1");">one</li><li  onmouseover="javascript:showDiv("div2");">two</li>(4 li)</ul>
```

where showDiv(id) shows a div and hides the other div.

The divs:

```
<div id="menu1">menu1</div>
<div id="menu2" style="display:none;">menu2</div>
<div id="menu3" style="display:none;">menu3</div>
<div id="menu4" style="display:none;">menu4</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function fadeBetweenDivs( div1, div2 ) {
 $$( div1 ).fade( "out" );
 (function(){
  $$( div1 ).setStyles({
   display: 'none',
   opacity: 0
  });
 }).delay( 150 );
 (function(){
  $( div2 ).setStyles({
   display: 'block',
   opacity: 0
  });
 }).delay( 150 );
 $$( div2 ).fade( "in" );
}
function findDiv() {
 var arrayDiv = ["menu1","menu2","menu3","menu4"];
 for (i=0;i<arrayDiv.length;i++) {
  var blockDiv = document.getElementById(arrayDiv[i]).style.display;
  if (blockDiv = "block") {
   var viewedDiv = arrayDiv[i];
   return viewedDiv;
  }
 }
}
function showDiv(showdiv) {
 var hidediv = findDiv();
 fadeBetweenDivs(hidediv,showdiv);
}
```

The code addEvent etc. works, I'll not paste it here. The function executed is showDiv("div id"); .

I can't find the problem. Can you tell me how to make it work or at least a simpler way to fade the divs?

(Mootools works, I'm using Joomla)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors within your code. 
I tried to make a little example to help you understand the problem and to easily find a solution.
Hope it helps!

http://goo.gl/TzlSt

If you have any doubts, please feel free to ask me ;)

Comment: `$$('.menu').fade(0).setStyle('display','none');` - fade is asynchronous and cannot be chained like so, it will effectively hide it due to display and then tween the fade to 0 but not so that the user can see. use `el.set("tween", { onComplete: function() { this.element.setStyle("display", "none"); }).fade("0");` - although you need to `el.get("tween").removeEvents();` before you do other tweens like fade in. also, you should cache the selectors - this can be very slow/ineffective with a large data set and an older browser. p.s. this is for 1.2 so not joomla 1.5 (unless custom'd)

Comment: Right Dimitar! It was only a simple example to let Ken know the way to solve that problem! Thanks to let me and him know the way the code can be improved. By the way I knew about fade, but it was just a way to "reset" the opacity, same by doing setStyle('opacity',0). To let the user see the effect, another way can be done by chaining an Fx.Morph. I agree with you also about caching.. when I'll have 5 mins I'll fix the code ;)

Comment: i realise you know this but the person that asked the question or those that will look at the solution may not. :)